# Requesting Facebook friends count in Swift 3

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, swift3, authentication

I'm trying to get the user Facebook friends count in Swift 3, but I found some problems:

First of all, I created this code based on [Facebook Documention](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends):

```
func getNumberOfFriends() {

    let parameters = ["fields": "summary"]
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/friends", parameters: parameters, httpMethod: "GET").start { (connection, result, error) in

        let userInformations = User.instance

        if let error = error {
            print("erro: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        if let result = result as? [String: AnyObject] {

            if let summary = result["summary"] as? NSDictionary {
                if let total_count = summary["total_count"] as? Int {
                    userInformations.numberOfFriends = total_count
                    self.getFriendsCountDelegate?.didGetFriendsCount(error:false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I'm receiving an empty data response. I think the problem could be a strange thing I found in my Login: I'm requesting these permissions:

```
var loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()    
self.loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "user_friends",  "email", "user_posts"]
self.loginButton.publishPermissions = ["publish_actions"]
```

but when I check those permissions, I found that I don't have it! I only have "public_profile" and "publish_actions".

When I check my FacebookApp Page, I see that it seems ok:

**All permissions are ok on my Facebook App Page**
[image]

Does somebody could help me? I don't know what else should I do!
Thank you

Comment: Did the user grant the permission also? It is not enough that you ask the user. The user need to grant the permission also

Comment: the screenshot is irrelevant, those are just the basic permission that are approved by default. approval !== authorization.

Comment: Did you add "user_friends",  "email", "user_posts" permissions after you click for the first time on your Facebook button? You may have accepted only public_profile permissions the first time you connect, and if you change permissions after your first connection, it will not be saved for the old connections. Try to remove the app authorisation from your Facebook account (in your settings) and try again. Does it work?

Comment: Yes, I removed the app authorisation from my Facebook account, but the problem persists. The Facebook authorisation page inside my app only ask me permission for my public_profile.

Comment: You can not ask for reading and publishing permissions at the same time in native mobile apps.